# Probability of Winning in Magic: The Gathering

Tags: probability, card-games

In the trading card game [Magic: The Gathering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic:_The_Gathering), there is the opportunity for combos to extend infinitely. Since some cards involve probabilistic events, it is possible for a combo to be nondeterministic in outcome. For example, in [this video](https://youtu.be/mKZ-ibOkRzs) by FishMTG, a situation is contrived in which the opponent has 4 life and controls only a tapped [Leonin Elder](https://scryfall.com/card/mrd/10/leonin-elder), and the active player player can activate a [Wirefly Hive](https://scryfall.com/card/dst/161/wirefly-hive) as many times as they want. The effect of this is that a coin is flipped repeatedly:

- On heads, the active player gets a $2$ damage attacker and the
  opponent gains $1$ health.
- On tails, the active player loses all of their attackers.

If the active player gets attacking damage equal or greater than the opponent's health, they can attack and win the game. The question is how probable is it for the active player to win? Even though they infinite opportunities to get the flips necessary, the longer they go, the more heads in a row they need. Precisely, they need a run of heads that is greater than or equal to half of (the total number of heads$+4)$

Coding a simulation in python, I get an approximate answer of $0.183$ (with a max health of 10000 because the chance of getting 10000 heads in a row is almost impossible). You can read my (very bad) code [here](https://pastebin.com/nCYEvTqE). But I'd like to know how to calculate a more precise answer.

Comment: I think so. The only issue is that it seems $n=4$ for the specific situation presented in the video. But the answer from my simulation matches $n=3$ in @leonbloy's answer.

Comment: (also crazy that you asked the same question 10 years ago and found my question within an hour of posting it)

Comment: Wait I understand the notation change in his answer. 4 or more means exceeding 3.